# Xen bridge - block traffic from port range - iptables / ebtables

Tags: iptables, xen, bridge, traffic, block

I use Xen with bridge interface :
- eth0
- viifbr0
- Name of VM interface : vifv10XX.0

Do you know if it is possible to block output traffic from source port range for a domU please ?

If yes, can you say how to do that please ?

I tried with iptables but the traffic isn't blocked for the VM.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you want to run the firewall on the hypervisor, the dom0 or on the guest OS? For the first scenario you'll need to apply your rules on the [`FORWARD`](http://serverfault.com/a/301986/37681) chain.

Comment: Yes, the firewall runs on Hypervisor dom0